# Maintaining Synchronization using JAVA and JNI

Tags: java, c++, multithreading

I have been struggling to accomplish a GUI driven task that is initiated in a thread that takes a while to compute and is also accomplished over the JNI using C++ native code.  When the computationally intensive task is run, the synchronization is lost, otherwise, synchronization is fine.

Can someone help with an implementation structure where synchronization of the time is not lost?  I have a hunch it is because my use of JNI.

The structure of the my problem is below:

1) A button (animate) is selected and triggers an event for a GUI listener

2) GUI recognized that the button was pressed and starts a thread below:

3) Once button is pressed again, the thread closes.

```
private class Animator implements Runnable
{

    public void start()
    {
        if (thread == null)
        {
             thread = new Thread(this, "Animator");
             thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
         while (animate.isSelected())
         {
             updateAnimations();
         }
         resetAnimations();
         thread = null;
    }

    public void updateAnimations()
    {
        double time = scene.getTime(); // A singleton class and scene time
        time += 10;
        scene.update(time); // the scene updates its parameters to time and redraws the GUI.  One of the computations is done over the JNI and takes too long and synchronization is lost (i.e. time = [10 40 80 ...])
    }

    Thread thread;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `synchronization`?  can you describe your problem in more detail?  synchronization has a particular meaning with respect to java and multithreading and is probably not the word you want to use here.

Comment: You are right  Thanks.  I am not multithreading so I do not believe that another thread is executing the same scene.update(time) code.  By synchronization, I mean that it appears that the time variable is change more rapidly than the scene is update.  For example, time increment two times for each scene update and thus the events in the GUI are not sequential.